# Is the inverse of a one-to-one function also a one-to-one function?

Tags: functions

If I have a function that is one-to-one, is the inverse also one-to-one?

Comment: If it were not, then the original function would not even be a "function".

Comment: Mostly true.  First, the inverse of a one-to-one function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is only a function on the image of $f$.  We assume that $f$ is either onto or that we're only looking at the image.  The statement that $f$ is one-to-one is exactly the same as the statement that $f^{-1}$ is a function.  Since $f$ is a function, this means that $f^{-1}$ is one-to-one because $f^{-1}$ being one-to-one is exactly the same as $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$ being a function.

Answer (score 1):

An injective (one-to-one) function doesn't have to have an inverse.

For example if you have a sets $ A = \{ 0,1 \} $ and $B = \{ 2,3,4\}$.  You could have a function $f = \{ (0,2) , (1,3) \} $. There doesn't exist an inverse in this case.

Normally when we talk about an inverse though we are looking for functions $ f : D \to C $ and $ f^{-1} : C \to D $ so that $ f(f^{-1}(x)) = x $ and $ f^{-1}(f(x)) =x $.  In this situation $f^{-1}$ must be injective.

Comment: +1. To the OP: of course there *is* an inverse if we replace $B$ with the range of $f$. So every injective function "almost" has an inverse.

Comment: Does the existence of inverse is guaranteed?

Comment: @mathlover I can't quite parse your comment.

Answer (score 0):

$f:A\rightarrow B$ is one-one and assuming that $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$ exists necessitates that $f$ is onto which clearly suggests that $f^{-1}$ is a bijection (one-one and onto).